# vb.net list how to sort and display

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a list that is is populated by a DB query:

```
Dim bplist As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
```

What I want to do is sort the list in order of largest Integer to smallest and then display both Key and Value of this list in the HTML part of my .aspx page.

I've googled around quite a bit and only managed to confuse myself.  Can someone please help me with this?  Thanks.

Comment: The fastest way would be to order the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linq query to accomplish this

```
dim bplist as List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
dim sortedList as List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) = bplist.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.value).toList
```

In order to bind the keys and values to HTML, I would suggest taking a look at [repeaters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)

**Note**

This is assuming that when you say you want to sort by the highest to lowest integer, that you are meaning the value

Comment: I think Linq is going to complicate this a bit.

Comment: Why would you say that? This example just returns it as a sorted list

OrderByDescending is a linq statement

Comment: No problem :) it happens to all of us

Comment: Dan, thank you.  Yes, I meant sort by the value.  So, I'm a little confused... never worked with lists.  Does that automatically make "sorted" a list or do I need to declare it as one?  Also, I have no idea how to display "sorted" or any list in html.  If you could at least give me a clue how to do that I can go from there..  Thanks!